# Setting up Jenkins + Gerrit

Tags: jenkins, gerrit

I need to setup an environment where jenkins builds the project right after I submited code for a review on gerrit. If it builds successfully jenkins gives +1 on gerrit review.

For gerrit integration I have used this manual: http://www.infoq.com/articles/Gerrit-jenkins-hudson

But I got staked at "Integration with Gerrit" step, on the instruction: "Create another job with the following:... Advanced (above repository browser) Choosing strategy".

I just dont have a strategy picker.

[image: SCM settings]

Gerrit Trigger version is v2.17.2;
Jenkins version is 1.635.

I suppose this setting was moved on new versions to somewhere else. In the plugin manual there is a screenshot of jenkins job setting and there is a strategy picker: 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger

How do I solve this problem? Are there any other ways to integrate gerrit into jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

The article is pretty old... I started up my old Jenkins VM, the Gerrit Plugin is 2.12.0 amd Jenkins 1.594.... hope that this helps you.

[image: Configuraion screenshot]